# Counts of groups

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a table with a text column that contains various bits of data.

For example

```
Hello world  
This is a piece of text  
Q1 3  
New text  
Q2 2  
Q1 2  
Q1 3  
More text
```

The bits of text trhat have Q1 at the start are pieces of voting data and are the bits I am interested in.

How can I write a query that gets counts of voting data only, so for example from the table data above it would return

```
Q1:2 counts 1  
Q1:3 counts 2  
Q2:2 counts 1
```

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a group by count, and use a WHERE to limit the cases you want:

```
SELECT table.textcol, COUNT(table.textcol)
FROM table
WHERE table.textcol LIKE "Q%"
GROUP BY table.textcol
ORDER BY table.textcol
```

This will output

```
Q1 2 -> 1
Q1 3 -> 2
Q1 1-> 1
```

Change the `LIKE` to a [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html) if you want more control (but watch the indexes, a `LIKE` with the `%` at the end can use an index, a `REGEXP` not).

Comment: Thanks for this that is exactly what I need. How would I further refine this to not include a text comment that was "Q2 2 blah lblah"?

Comment: Well if you are always sure the format will be 'Q1 3', you can use REGEXP, as I said. `/Q[0-9] [0-9]+/` should work.

Comment: This sounds interesting but I have never used REGEXP. How does that fit into the sql command? The fomat would always be Q## ## where the hashes could be single or double digit numbers.

Comment: `WHERE textcol REGEXP '^Q[0-9]+ [0-9]+$'` should do. Search for "regular expressions" on google or check the REGEXP link in my answer to learn more, it's really useful!

Comment: You're welcome. If this post answered your question, you can accept it, so the question is resolved and future visitors know this is a valid answer.